# Write Values found by Pandas Dataframe's .loc function into an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a google spreadsheet which i managed to load into a pandas dataframe:

```
Tag1    Tag2    Tag3    Tag4    Tag5    MobileNo
Blue    Yellow  Green   Velvet  Red     12345678
Blue    Yellow  Pink    Grey            234556778
Red     Yellow  Orange  Velvet          4456568
Red     Yellow  Grey    Blue            3454655467
```

Now i am not really familiar with pandas.
I would need all MobileNo which have a tag in one of the 5 tag columns within their rows to be written into an array.

Like

```
tag_red_results = ['12345678', '4456568', '3454655467']
```

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) :

```
# is the MobileNo tagged as "Red" ?
m = df.filter(like="Tag").eq("Red").any(axis=1)

s = df.loc[m, "MobileNo"]
```

If a list is needed, then use [`pandas.Series.to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) :

```
tag_red_results = s.to_list()
#[12345678, 4456568, 3454655467]
```

Or, if you need a numpy array, use [`pandas.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) :

```
tag_red_results = s.to_numpy()
#array([  12345678,    4456568, 3454655467], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `melt` to flatten your tag columns:

```
>>> df.melt('MobileNo').loc[lambda x: x['value'] == 'Red', 'MobileNo'].tolist()
[4456568, 3454655467, 12345678]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Timeless!

your solution worked perfectly!

Below is my code:

```
def readColorsDataFromClientSheet(sheetId, tag):
    ss = sheets[sheetId]
    df = ss.find('Colors').to_frame(index_col='Clients')
    tagged = df.filter(like='Tag').eq(tag).any(axis=1)
    mobile_numbers = df.loc[tagged, "MobileNo"].tolist()
    print(mobile_numbers)
return mobile_numbers
```